# Does draw geometryFunction still work in openlayers 6?

Tags: openlayers-6

I try to use geometryFunction to get and put the coordinate in some html table.
so I use this example (for OL3)
[jsfiddle by Jonatas Walker](https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/8b322285/)

```
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: vectorSource,
  type: "LineString",
  geometryFunction: function(coords, geom) {
    if (!geom) geom = new ol.geom.LineString(null);
    geom.setCoordinates(coords);
    //if linestring changed
    if(coords.length !== coords_length){
      coords_length = coords.length;
      coords_element.innerHTML = coords.join('<br>');
    }
    return geom;
  }
});
map.addInteraction(draw);
```

I made a fork and change the version for 6.2.1 for ol.js and css
[this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jipexu/bLw0v7jk/6/)

and I get this error (multiple times .....) Draw.js line 683

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.sketchFeature_.getGeometry')
```

I try to find why but for now any idea ...

Comment: A LineString is created from a coordinate array.  Change `if (!geom) geom = new ol.geom.LineString(null);` to `if (!geom) geom = new ol.geom.LineString([]);` and your code will work

Comment: @Mike you are genius ! i dont want to abuse of your knowledge but why this pass in v3 and not in v6 ? Thanks !!

Comment: It changed in version 5 https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v5.1.0

Comment: ok i see thanks (and it's write on the first line ! ....)